# Некорректно выводится текст

Tags: linux, c

У меня есть файл со следующим текстом

> ﻿{"dbRowID":354,"devID":"868183036078249","tsrs":[{"id":97655,"lat":50.55909166666667,"lon":36.55319

и так далее.Файл имеет кодировку UTF-8
[image: Кодировка текстового файла]

У меня есть код:

```
int main() {
FILE *file_input;
FILE *file_output;
char *input = "struct.txt";
char symbol;

/*Открываем фаил*/
do{
    if((file_input = fopen(input, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Файл с данными отстутствует.\n");
        printf("\'qq\' для выхода");
    }
    else if(input == "qq") {
        scanf("%s", &input);
    }
    }while(file_input == NULL); 

/*Заполняем массив структур*/
while((symbol = fgetc(file_input))) {
    printf("%c", symbol);

}
fclose(file_input);

return 0;
```

}

И вместо вывода текст, у меня терминал выдаёт:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При при использовании команды cat struct.txt в терминале у меня выводится корректный текст. Из-за чего это может быть? Как это исправить? И с какой кодировкой линукс работает нормально UTF-8 или ASCI?

Comment: Линукс нормально работает с обеими кодировками. Ошибка в `char symbol;` Напишите `int symbol` и `while ((symbol = fgetc(file_input)) != EOF) ...` / Почему `int` а не `char`? Подумайте сами (или задайте соответствующий вопрос)

Comment: Полно же готовых парсеров JSON. Зачем мучаетесь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Линукс нормально работает с обеими кодировками. Ошибка в char symbol; Напишите int >symbol и while ((symbol = fgetc(file_input)) != EOF).

Проблема возникала из-за отстутствия проверки на файла на конец (как я понял). После изменения условия цикла `while((symbol = fgetc(file_input)) != EOF)` текс начал выводиться.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам поможет это:

```
#include <locale.h>
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```